# TestFlight: I added new device to PP, should I upload new build to testflight?

Tags: testflight

I uploaded build to testFlight, then my friend ask me to give him possibility to download app from testFlight. So I get his UDID and added to Provisioning profile.

1. Should I create new build and upload it to testFlight ? If Yes, is there any option to no do that ? I dont want to confuse others users with new build, because there is no changes there...
2. Should my friend install testFlight app and register on test flight  on iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can upload new provisioning profile in permission section on testflight without uploading new ipa